# What is the formula needed to solve this question? (combinations and permutations)

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, permutations, combinations

I want to solve this on my own, what is the formula needed to solve this type of question?

> How many hands contain a straight flush (that is, 5 consecutive cards of the same suit, where aces can be low or high) that is not a royal straight flush?

Answer (score 2):

**HINTS**

1. How many choices to fix the suit?
2. How many choices for the top card in the straight flush? (Hint: can 3 be the top card?)